# Optimize table design for "SQL Where Clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, self-referencing-table

I am working on a database design for Where clauses of SQL. My application is a workflow engine that allows the end-user to specify the where clause of an SQL. Currently my application supports creation of where clause as follows:

```html
<input type="text" name="clause-name" placeholder="condition name here" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="where">Complex</input>
<br/>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <select>
    <option value="1">ch4 &ge; 1.5</option>
    <option value="2">locality = chino</option>
    <option value="3">postal_code like [0-9]{5}</option>
    <option value="4">date &le; 2015-12-31</option>
    <option value="5">chino and ch4</option>
    <option value="6">postalcode and date</option>
    <option value="7">chino or postalcode</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>AND</option>
    <option>OR</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option value="1">ch4 &ge; 1.5</option>
    <option value="2">locality = chino</option>
    <option value="3">postal_code like [0-9]{5}</option>
    <option value="4">date &le; 2015-12-31</option>
    <option value="5">chino and ch4</option>
    <option value="6">postalcode and date</option>
    <option value="7">chino or postalcode</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="where">Simple</input>
<br/>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <select>
    <option>ch4</option>
    <option>locality</option>
    <option>postal_code</option>
    <option>date</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>&le;</option>
    <option>&lt;</option>
    <option>&ge;</option>
    <option>&gt;</option>
    <option>&ne;</option>
    <option>=</option>
    <option>like</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="value here" />
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button>Create Condition</button>
```

On some other page I've a select dropdown where you choose the created clause. The problem is the database table I designed for this scenario. It is as follows right now:

`WhereTable(id, name, feature, op, value, condition1, jointype, condition2)`

such that `id` is primary key and `condition1, condition2` are foreign keys on self. A sample table for the condition `(ch4 >= 1.5 and locality = chino) or (postal_code like [0-9]{5} and date <= 2015-12-31)` would be as follows:

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>feature</th>
    <th>op</th>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>condition1</th>
    <th>jointype</th>
    <th>condition2</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ch4&ge;1.5</td>
    <td>ch4</td>
    <td>&gt;=</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>locality=chino</td>
    <td>locality</td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>chino</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>postal_code like [0-9]{5}</td>
    <td>postal_code</td>
    <td>like</td>
    <td>[0-9]{5}</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>date&le;2015-12-31</td>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>&lt;=</td>
    <td>2015-12-31</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>chino and ch4</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>and</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>postalcode and date</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>and</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>chino or postalcode</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>or</td>
    <td>6</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Is there any way I can optimize this table design to reduce the null values? I'm using MySQL as my database server.

Comment: Which table design are you asking about? This is about database design, but you show an HTML <table>, which is a little bit uncommon as a representation for database content.

If we're talking about database design, those null values shouldn't be a problem with any decent database. Just define the attributes you need and put an index on those that are frequently queried. If you have any particular problem still, please be more specific.

Comment: @TAM - Thanks for taking time to look into this. I'm talking about the table `WhereTable(id, name, feature, op, value, condition1, jointype, condition2)`. The html table is just an illustration of how the values look like in the database. The problem is that, in every row, nulls would be present either in the columns `condition1, jointype, condition2` or the columns `feature, op, value`. I'm curious to know if I can optimize the design to minimize these null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, now I think I understand.

In object oriented terms, you have an inheritance structure like

```
Formula
   int id
   String name

BasicFormula extends Formula
   String variable
   Operator operator  // something like <=, contains, ...
   String value

CompoundFormula extends Formula
   Formula leftFormula
   Operator operator  // and, or
   Formula rightFormula
```

Now, to map such a construct to a database, there are different strategies. It's perfectly legal to use table-per-class-hierarchy, which is what you suggested, just having a table that contains the attributes of both specializations. A detailed description is given in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html. In many cases having just one table is the easiest solution. Of course, anyone querying the database will have to know how to interpret the scheme, but this holds for the other strategies as well.

Comment: I liked your way of representing it in object-oriented terms but the problem with the CompoundFormula class in your solution is that the leftFormula and rightFormula could be either BasicFormula or CompoundFormula. I guess that changing the datatype to Formula might help here as it is the super class of both. I'll try to implement this and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure, should have been Formula. I'll edit the answer.